# Windows lock up randomly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, catalina

The application windows on my 2017 Macbook pro MacOS 10.15 lock up randomly and I don’t know what triggers it. When this happens I can’t switch to a different window in a different desktop using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or view desktops using <kbd>F3</kbd>, and launch pad won’t open up (launchpad can only be accessed by two finger clicking the launchpad icon in the bottom application tray). I can only switch between application windows by using control and the arrow keys. The only way to fix this window locking up problem is to reboot the system, although once or twice the windows randomly unlock after a long period of time.

Am I inadvertently pressing a key that locks up operating system windows so that they become unresponsive to keyboard presses?

What is causing application windows to lock up on MacOS 10.15?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Weird behavior... Does it happen with specific apps (which?) or is it a general problem with all apps? When did the problem start happening (update, app installation, driver installation)? Are windows in full screen?

Comment: @jaume it happens with every app. I don't remember when it started, maybe a few months ago, it's a new Macbook pro so I've not had it long. Some windows are full screen, some are not.

Comment: It could be an issue with your mouse or your trackpad. If this happens when using a mouse, could you use your trackpad instead and see if the problem still occurs? If it happens with uour trackpad, could you use a mouse instead?

Comment: @jaume I have no mouse. Selecting app icons using command + tab does not switch to the selected app. I can still scroll using the trackpad, that's not the problem. I just can't switch between applications.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right, it is clearly not a mouse/trackpad issue.

Comment: @jaume after leaving my notebook in sleep mode overnight, the operating system windows randomly unlocked, and now I can switch between application windows again.